# Understanding range locking for select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to understand why transaction 1 is blocking transaction 2. The locking hints on the select queries are generated by Hibernate (`LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`) and part of a larger transaction. I suspect that my indices are the reason why the first is blocking the second transaction:

Transaction 1:

```
begin transaction
select * from mytable with (updlock,holdlock,rowlock) where a='A1' and b='X' and c='Y' and d='Z'
waitfor delay '00:00:20'
commit transaction
```

Transaction 2:

```
begin transaction
select * from mytable with (updlock,holdlock,rowlock) where a='A2' and b='X' and c='Y' and d='Z'
commit transaction
```

For each select I get a single row as a result. I would expect that T1 does not block T2 as T2 selects a different `a`.

The table schema looks like this:

```
create table mytable
(
  id bigint not null constraint PK_mytable primary key,
  a varchar(12) constraint FK_a references dbo.othertable1,
  b varchar(255),
  c varchar(255),
  d varchar(255) not null,
  constraint FK_b_c foreign key (b, c) references dbo.othertable2
)
go

create index IX_a_b_c_d on dbo.mytable (a, b, c, d)
go

create index IX_b_c on dbo.mytable (b, c)
go

create index IX_a on dbo.mytable (a)
go

create index IX_d on dbo.mytable (d)
go
```

When I run only T1 and run `exec sp_lock` I get the following output:

| ObjId | IndId | Type | Resource | Mode | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 1 | KEY | (fffffffffff) | RangeS-U | GRANT |
| 42 | 1 | PAG | 1:630 | UI | GRANT |
| 42 | 1 | KEY | (22a25774a2a8) | RangeS-U | GRANT |
| 42 | 1 | KEY | (4b1b2249cf04) | RangeS-U | GRANT |
| 42 | 0 | TAB |  | IX | GRANT |

EDIT, here the whole DML:

```
create table dbo.othertable1
(
    a varchar(12) not null constraint PK_othertable1 primary key,
    b int         not null,
    c varchar(20),
    d date,
    e varchar(255),
    f varchar(20),
    g varchar(255),
    h bigint      not null,
    i bit,
    j varchar(255)
)
go

create index IX_c_f
    on dbo.othertable1 (c, f)
go


create table dbo.myothertable2
(
    a int not null,
    b varchar(255) not null,
    c varchar(255) not null,
    d date         not null,
    e date         not null,
    f bigint       not null,
    constraint PK_b_c
        primary key (b, c)
)
go


create table dbo.mytable
(
    id bigint not null constraint PK_mytable primary key,
    a varchar(12) constraint FK_othertable1 references dbo.othertable1,
    b varchar(255),
    c varchar(255),
    d varchar(255) not null,
    e                    bigint       not null,
    f    bit          not null,
    g                  varchar(255),
    h       datetime2,
    i     varchar(255),
    j datetime2,
    k           bit,
    constraint FK_b_c
        foreign key (b, c) references dbo.myothertable2
)
go

create index IX_a_b_c_d
    on dbo.mytable (a, b, c, d)
go

create index IX_b_c
    on dbo.mytable (b, c)
go

create index IX_a
    on dbo.mytable (a)
go

create index IX_d
    on dbo.mytable (d)
go

insert into othertable1 values ('A1', '0', '', '2024-01-25', '','','',0,0,'')
go
insert into othertable1 values ('A2', '0', '', '2024-01-25', '','','',0,0,'')
go
insert into myothertable2 values (0, 'X', 'Y', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', 0)
go
insert into mytable values (1, 'A1', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0, 0, '', '2024-01-01', '', '2024-01-01', 0)
go
insert into mytable values (2, 'A2', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0, 0, '', '2024-01-01', '', '2024-01-01', 0)
go
```

Comment: What does your Java code (I assume) do? What do you mean by `part of a larger transaction`? And why is `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` used? All this is a smell - *reading* in an ORM, whether Hibernate or Entity Framework, doesn't need transactions. Since the late 1990s applications use optimistic concurrency instead of long running transactions that cover both reading and writing. The difference in performance is several orders of magnitude and increases the more traffic an application gets

Comment: It really helps if you also provide DML for sample data to go with your DDL; otherwise we have to make up data and they *might* not replicate your problem.

Comment: Part of a larger transaction means that there is a check whether an entry for some key exists and if not a new entry is inserted. There are many parallel requests sometimes for the same key, thats why pessimistic locking is used. The problem is that there is a unwanted locking situation for a select query for different keys (example above).

Comment: Index id of `1` is the clustered index. So presumably the execution plan is doing a clustered index scan instead of any kind of index seek. As the CI is on `id` this means that it is going to lock all of the rows rather than a range (including the infinite range at the end `fffffffffff`). So you only have two rows?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, I have only two rows in the test database that leads to the locking situation. In the production database there are way more than two rows.

Comment: So you need to find out why the index you have provided on `a, b, c, d` isn't being used. Might there be an issue with parameter datatypes? `nvarchar` vs `varchar`? Or in reality does the index not cover all of the columns in the query as returned by `select * `?

Comment: I added the whole DML in my edit to reproduce the locking.

Comment: the reason why you get a clustered index scan is because the index doesn't include columns `e,f,g,h,i,j,k` - do you need to `SELECT *` here?

Comment: If I run `select a, b, c, d from [...]` the locking still takes place.

Comment: @user15110545 what you say points to misuse of Hibernate. Hibernate, like all ORMs, tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows. If you want to insert a row if a key doesn't exist, execute `INSERT .... WHERE NOT EXISTS (id=@id)` directly. What are the *actual* parallel operations ? Even if a double POST resulted in an attempt to insert the same thing twice, one of the operations would fail *as it should* and not persist anything. You'd only have issues if you used an IDENTITY or client-generated key, which isn't shown here

Comment: `the locking still takes place` locking always takes place. Locks are taken on every SELECT and maintained until the transaction or connection closes. That's why ORMs *don't* keep connections open unless you force them by using long running transactions. They read the data you asked, return the objects and then close the connection.

Comment: BTW you still haven't posted your Hibernate code. That's what causing the problem. Even without the block, all parallel operations will see that the PK value doesn't exist and try to insert it at the same time. You still have the duplicate key problem but now it's hidden behind the block

Comment: In fact, the block is *required* to do what you want. The server must ensure all parallel operations get the same result which means it has to lock as many rows as possible to ensure the result doesn't change. That's equivalent to the REPEATABLE READ isolation level, which is stricter than the common READ COMMITTED mode.